# How to solve material-ui button focus accessibility issue

Tags: css, button, material-ui, accessibility

Buttons from `material-ui` have a focus effect, but the accessibility checker complains that it's not using the `:focus` property in CSS.

[image: Button with focus]

For example, this highlighted English dropdown has a focus effect, but when I try an accessibility check, it has the following results:

[image: Element not highlighted on focus]

Do you think I can ignore this issue whenever I use buttons from material-ui, or is there a solution for this?

Comment: To be clear are you on about the 'pulsing' focus indicators that seem to 'breath'. As long as the contrast ratio is OK (as I noticed on some of them the contrast ratio looks a little low once the indicator is showing) they are acceptable and you can ignore this as it is mis-reporting (and your application doesn't work without JS so that isn't a concern). Another thing to consider is if a user has preference for reduced motion, does the pulsing stop? they may find it distracting (can fix it with media queries - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion)